# Is it possible to send push notifications to mobile devices without using cloud based notification engine

Tags: android, ios, azure, windows-mobile

I've been asked to look investigate the possible writing of a mobile application for devices that we have out in the field. These devices currently connect back to the office over a secure APN so therefore do not have access to the internet, is it possible to send push notifications to a device that can't access the internet, from the little research I've done so far it looks like the the notification engines are cloud based on azure for example.

Can you host anything locally or is that just not possible?

Comment: To send push notification to devices the client sending the push notification needs to be connect to the internet. So if you server send the push notification it will need to be connect to the internet. Also the device receiving the notification needs a internet connection. Since Apple/Google servers push to the device over the internet.

Comment: By "can't connect to the internet" do you mean the public internet, or not to anything?  In the first case yes-  you can write your own implementation of push messaging from scratch (push messaging is basically just a TCP socket to a server) or use one of the several open source implementations.If you mean there's no connection even to a private WAN, then no.

Comment: @GabeSechan this will be difficult on iOS since running apps in the background has al kinds of special requirements.

Comment: Possibly, I came to the question from the Android tag. Yet another reason why I wouldn't use Apple hardware for anything

Comment: The devices only connect back to the office over a APN so the devices cannot access the internet outside of the APN. Unfortunately this has been forced on us by the contracts that we have with our clients.

Answer (score 0):

You can send the push notification only from a device that is connected to the Internet. But the receiving device does not have to be connected to the Internet at the time. The notification will be queued and when the receiving device establishes an internet connection, then it will receive it. But beware, if you send a second notification to the second device before the first one has been received, only the second will be kept.